# How to implement datatables in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatable, datatables

***I have hardcoded some sample data to check weather datatable is taking place or not***

***table.blade.php***

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <!--<div class="col-md-8  col-md-offset-2">-->
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading">table</div>
           <div class="panel-body">
              @if (session('status'))
              <div class="alert alert-success">
                 {{ session('status') }}
              </div>
              @endif
<table class="table" id="table">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
           <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
           <th class="text-center">Email</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>3</td>
       </tr>       
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

***Initializing css / js in header page***

```
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"> 
</head>
```

***Javascript***

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#table').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

> No error but not showing paging and search option

Comment: Could try [laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)

Comment: I dont know how to use this if possible can you guide me.. :) because I am using Laravel 5.5 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done paging using following code but not thorough /datatable lib.
Add this following code next to `</table>` tag.

**table.blade.php**

```
 {!! $viewalltask->links() !!}
```

Update also controller 
**controller.php**

```
public function viewalltask()
{
    $viewalltask = DB::table('tasks')->paginate(5);
    return view('viewalltask', ['viewalltask' => $viewalltask]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `js` files are not loaded properly.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: I have replaced those files but still same :(

Comment: @Rakesh Any error occurs in the console?  Do not forget to add in the head
`<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#table').DataTable();
} );
</script>`

Comment: @Rakesh  can you update your question with full blade file content with all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a yeild in your layout.blade

```
@yield('scripts')
```

In your page, put a section('scripts'):

```
@section('scripts')
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#table').DataTable();
       } );
       </script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datatables try to load before the page is finished loading. Defer your scripts, so they only load after the page has loaded:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js" defer></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Two ways:
1) env file in put database name 
2) database.php file conection in set database name

Comment: He is not talking about a database. His concern about datatable 
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap